# slam_toolbox receiving DDS messages in burst

Tags: ros2, dds, message-filter

In my system (ROS2 Humble, SICK lidars at 15-20Hz, Ubuntu 22, Cyclone DDS, ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1), the SLAM toolbox (localization mode) is dropping lots of scan messages because it seems to process them in bursts:

```
[laser_merger-26] [INFO] [1702299520.577923168] [laser_merger]: Scan timestamp 1702299520.568154380
[laser_merger-26] [INFO] [1702299520.637141685] [laser_merger]: Scan timestamp 1702299520.628157395
[laser_merger-26] [INFO] [1702299520.692687410] [laser_merger]: Scan timestamp 1702299520.685429963  # This one will be dropped
[laser_merger-26] [INFO] [1702299520.761680120] [laser_merger]: Scan timestamp 1702299520.745150593  # This one will be dropped
[laser_merger-26] [INFO] [1702299520.810470294] [laser_merger]: Scan timestamp 1702299520.805417360  # This one will be dropped
[laser_merger-26] [INFO] [1702299520.879494873] [laser_merger]: Scan timestamp 1702299520.862291115  # This one will be dropped
[laser_merger-26] [INFO] [1702299520.935199630] [laser_merger]: Scan timestamp 1702299520.920191075
[localization_slam_toolbox_node-14] [INFO] [1702299520.978097929] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_merged' at time 1702299520.685 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[localization_slam_toolbox_node-14] [INFO] [1702299520.978407187] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_merged' at time 1702299520.745 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[localization_slam_toolbox_node-14] [INFO] [1702299520.978597188] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_merged' at time 1702299520.805 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[localization_slam_toolbox_node-14] [INFO] [1702299520.978782668] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_merged' at time 1702299520.862 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'
[laser_merger-26] [INFO] [1702299520.982368570] [laser_merger]: Scan timestamp 1702299520.978653345
[laser_merger-26] [INFO] [1702299521.041055448] [laser_merger]: Scan timestamp 1702299521.038272160
```

This then lead to many TF extrapolation issues in my system as the burst is sometime delayed more than 1s (corresponding to my slam_toolbox.transform_timeout param, aka. an offset in the future for TF).
The number of messages dropped and TF delay increase as navigation time increases (no issue when robot is not navigating, when it is static).
My mean CPU usage is at 50% but I note spikes at 100% when these bursts occurs.

How can I investigate further ? (I'm out of idea)
How could I ensure an approximate 'regular' flow of message (ie. message approximately sent and received at the time they are published. I suspect this to also happen with other nodes)

Things I've tried so far (but no improvements):

- Playing with slam_toolbox.scan_queue_size: increasing from 1 to 10 just hides the log message
- Playing with slam_toolbox.transform_timeout: it make the TF issues start to appear later (makes me think that the delay is 'accumulating' somewhere, or maybe my CPU heat and decrease it frequency)
- Tuning the Linux buffers for DDS ([as here](https://autowarefoundation.github.io/autoware-documentation/main/support/troubleshooting/performance-troubleshooting/) and [there](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/DDS-tuning.html))
- Trying to improve my odometry rate by interpolating with robot_localization's ekf_filter ([inspired from here](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/issues/516))
- (seen the [related questions](https://answers.ros.org/question/324740/why-is-message-processing-in-sporadic-bursts/) but that are for ROS1)